# spring cloud stream and gcp pub sub, binder problem

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm tryng to run an SCS app locally using GCP's Pub Sum as binder.
K
    m
    mmkkkk. Mmm org.sm.Mpringframework.cloudkki
        spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub
    
M
Here is the config`l`

```
@Configu@Configukration
@EnableBindingkklk(Source.class)
public class TimerSourcek {

  @Bean
  @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
  public MessageSource<String> timerMessageSource() {
    return () -> new GenericMessage<>(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
  }
}
```

Here is the error message when starting the main app:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-13 15:42:48.627 ERROR 22276 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A default binder has been requested, but there is no binder available
```

I'd like to run this code either locally or against my GCP project. How can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub` doesn't bring for you a binder dependency. 
You need to use a `spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder` also:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

See samples in the project for more info: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples

Comment: The error is gone, but I was expecting a new topic called "inbox" would be created according to spring.cloudstream.bindings.output.destination=inbox, but it actually doesn't

Comment: Sounds like a new SO question with more details . It doesn’t work like a chat here...

Comment: Please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616745/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-a-default-binder-has-been-request